# What is the meaning of the sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, meaning

> > > Taking in with a wave of his hand the rich, black earth spreading all the way to the horizon, he exclaimed: “My God, what couldn’t we do with such wonderful land.” Then he added as an afterthought: “But I suppose we would have become like them.”

Could anyone explain me `Taking in with a wave of his hand the rich, black earth spreading all the way to the horizon`?

Comment: Could you explain what you don't understand?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: He waved his hand at the rich black earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**wave** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/226385?rskey=UkwWah&result=4&isAdvanced=true#eid15089744)

> a. trans. To move through the air with a **sweeping gesture** of the
>   uplifted or extended **arm or hand** often as a sign of greeting or
>   farewell, or as an expression of exultation

As in:

> Taking in with a **wave of his hand** (an expression of
>   exultation/rejoice) the rich, black earth spreading all the way to the
>   horizon.

Comment: I understand upto hand i.e. "Taking in with a wave of his hand" but what is use of the following words i.e. the rich...... Is the hand rich? what is the use of black earth here? is not it out of context?could you just paraphrase this sentence please?

Comment: rich black earth: fertile and fecund!

Comment: My head!! alas it does not get clenched in my head still!! Could you please write `Taking in with a wave of his hand the rich, black earth spreading all the way to the horizon, he exclaimed: “My God, what couldn’t we do with such wonderful land.”` in your own words please?

Comment: @SIslam *He waved his hand, gesturing to the rich, black earth that spread all the way to the horizon. "My God, " he exclaimed, "what couldn't we do with such wonderful land."*

Comment: Oh! I did not mind that wave is taking double object here!!#